# Prove that if f is continuous, than its borel function.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function continuous with respect to each coordinate ($x \mapsto f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{i-1},x,x_{i+1},\ldots,x_k)$ is continuous for every $i$). Prove that $f$ is a borel function.

Comment: Generally speaking on this site you should not use the imperative mode "Prove…", people do not wish to be commanded to do something. Also, you should give some context to your question, you should give some idea of what you do and do not understand about the question, and you should give some idea of what you have tried. If not, you risk wasting people's time.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will remember this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a function $f: \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be a Borel function if $f^{-1}(X)$ is a Borel set, for every Borel set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$.  Consider the class $\mathcal{F} = \{X \subset \mathbb{R} : f^{-1}(X)$ is Borel$\}$.

**Claim**: $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

**Proof**:  Since $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^k$ is Borel, $\mathcal{F} \neq \emptyset$.

Next, if $X \in \mathcal{F}$, then $f^{-1}(X)$ is a Borel set.  So, $\mathbb{R}^k \setminus f^{-1}(X)$ is a Borel set.  But $\mathbb{R}^k \setminus f^{-1}(X) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) \setminus f^{-1}(X) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} \setminus X)$.  Thus $\mathbb{R} \setminus X \in \mathcal{F}$.  So $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under compliments.

Finally, choose a countable sequence $\{X_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ in $\mathcal{F}$.  So $f^{-1}(X_j)$ is a Borel set, for each $j$.  So $\bigcup_j f^{-1}(X_j) = f^{-1}(\bigcup_j X_j)$ is Borel.  So $\bigcup_j X_j \in \mathcal{F}$.

This completes the claim.  Now just observe that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing every open set and thus every Borel set.